# NetworkManager - changing global DNS server

Tags: linux, networking, dns, networkmanager

So, to start off, this question isn't about the per-connection DNS setting NetworkManager has - this has [many](https://serverfault.com/questions/810636/how-to-manage-dns-in-networkmanager-via-console-nmcli) [answered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip) [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323459/how-to-make-networkmanager-add-a-dns-server-at-the-top-of-etc-resolv-conf) already and is well documented.

What I'm asking about is how to change the global DNS setting NetworkManager has, but to the best of my knowledge is exposed in neither Network Manager KDE GUI nor `nmcli` and isn't mentioned in `nmcli` or `nmcli-examples` manpage. The settings in question are `global-dns`, `global-dns-domains`, etc. and they are quite obscure, mentioned mostly in the [Gnome Developer Documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html).

In fact, I wouldn't even find out such a global DNS setting exists for NetworkManager if not for a Mullvad VPN instance that went tits up and left my `/etc/resolv.conf` filled permanently with `nameserver 10.64.0.1` - even setting per connection DNS didn't help with that, the global DNS overrode everything. In the investigation, running `nmcli` helped - there was a section with

```
DNS configuration:
        servers: 10.64.0.1
```

well below all the connections details, which hinted to me it's some kind of a global DNS setting. After grepping recursively `/home/`, `/etc/`, `/var/`, I finally found the `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager-intern.conf` file containing the following section:

```
# Internal section. Not overwritable via user configuration in 'NetworkManager.conf'
[.intern.global-dns-domain-*]
servers=10.64.0.1
options=
```

Which seems to be the culprit. Editing out this to be empty should be easy enough, however this part:

```
# Internal configuration file. This file is written and read
# by NetworkManager and its configuration values are merged
# with the configuration from 'NetworkManager.conf'.
(...)
#
# CHANGES TO THIS FILE WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

tells me I should probably shut down the `NetworkManager.service` before making changes to this file. So I basically tracked down and solved my issue (and described it here so possibly someone with a similar problem finds it less of a problem to find anything about it on the Internet), but I'm still left with questions:

1. Is this global DNS setting for the override purposes? If not, what purpose does it serve?
2. How did (I assume) the Mullvad VPN app make the changes to the variable?
3. Can this global DNS setting be changed via GUI or `nmcli`? What is the 'proper' way of changing it, as I assume modifying a `/var/lib/` file by hand while the service is shutdown is not a 'proper' solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while working on a similar problem.

I, too, want the same DNS configuration for every network connection. But I don't want to break a VPN, where internal DNS servers are probably necessary to resolve private hostnames. I think the answer is to embrace the Unix philosophy and let different tools do their job, configuring them to talk to each other.

For example, [this tutorial](https://andrea.corbellini.name/2020/04/28/ubuntu-global-dns/#step-2-disable-dns-processing-in-networkmanager) shows how to solve this problem by configuring `systemd-resolved` to use a global DNS server, and getting `NetworkManager` to stop telling `systemd-resolved` to use the DHCP-provided DNS server for each connection.

However, I suspect this configuration would break your VPN unless you override those two directives in the `[main]` section you use to get `NetworkManager` to stop managing DNS or telling `systemd-resolved` about what DHCP said about DNS. A VPN needs to use the internal DNS servers to resolve internal hostnames.

It's possible I'm wrong about this -- I haven't yet read about how NetworkManager plugins work, and it's possible that the VPN plugin could override those settings for you and you don't have to do anything manually. Try following that tutorial and testing your VPN first.

If you cannot resolve internal hostnames on your VPN, I think you could use an additional section to re-enable DHCP-provided DNS for your VPN link so that internal hostnames can be resolved. Maybe something like this:

```
[connection-vpn]
match-device=interface-name:tun0
dns=systemd-resolved
systemd-resolved=true
```

You'll have to fiddle with the `match-device` directive or use some other selector, depending on what your VPN connection looks like. Run `man NetworkManager.conf` and search for "Device List Format" to see some of the options. You could also choose an entirely different approach, like using `dnsmasq` or something.